# List ranking implementation in C with OpenMP -- Output error

Tags: c, openmp, pragma

The following code shows my implementation of list ranking algorithm with OpenMP. When I execute this code without the pragmas I get the correct results, but when I include the pragmas, I get errors (occasionally) in the output. The outputs are shown at the bottom. You can see that the second time the output was wrong. This occurs randomly. **When I remove the pragmas my output is always correct.** Is there an error in the way I used the pragmas or is there a dependency I am missing. 
(The sequential output is the expected output. When the parallel output matches sequential output the program prints DATA OK)

length and number of threads are 16.

```
#define NSIZE 1
#define NMAX 16
int Ns[NSIZE] = {16};
int A[NMAX] = {14,13,5,16,11,10,9,12,0,8,7,15,4,3,2,1}; 
int B[NMAX + 1] = {0};

int S[NMAX + 1] = {0};

int Rp[NMAX + 1] = {0};
int next[NMAX+1] = {0};

for(int i = 1, j=0; i <= n; i++, j++)
{
    B[i] = A[j];

}

int chunk = ceil(length/nthreads);
int i, j;
int tid;
//#pragma omp parallel num_threads(nthreads)
//{
//#pragma omp for schedule(dynamic, chunk) private(i)
for(i = 1; i <= length; i++)
{

    Rp[i] = 1;
    next[i] = S[i];
}


for(i = 1; i<=log2(length); i++)
{
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(nthreads) shared(Rp,next,chunk) private(j)
{
    #pragma omp for schedule(dynamic,chunk)
    for(j = 1; j <= length; j++)
    {
        if(next[j]!=0)
        {
            Rp[j] = Rp[j] + Rp[next[j]];

            next[j] = next[next[j]];
        }
    }

}
}
```

OUTPUT:

./a.out -- (This was the output when I ran the program the first time)

from parallel
data OK
Input:   14  13   5  16  11  10   9  12   0   8   7  15   4   3   2   1
Sequential:    6  10   4   8   3  15   1  13   0  14   2  12   9   5  11   7
Parallel :   6 10  4  8  3 15  1 13  0 14  2 12  9  5 11  7

./a.out -- (output when I ran the program the second time)
from parallel
data MISMATCH!!!
Input:   14  13   5  16  11  10   9  12   0   8   7  15   4   3   2   1
Sequential:    6  10   4   8   3  15   1  13   0  14   2  12   9   5  11   7
Parallel :   6 10  4  8  3 15  1 13  0 10  2 12  9  5 11  7

./a.out -- (output when I ran the program the third time)

from parallel
data OK
Input:   14  13   5  16  11  10   9  12   0   8   7  15   4   3   2   1
Sequential:    6  10   4   8   3  15   1  13   0  14   2  12   9   5  11   7
Parallel :   6 10  4  8  3 15  1 13  0 14  2 12  9  5 11  7

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include an actual [mcve]. Where are `Rp`, `next` and `S` defined? What are the random errors in output, are they actual errors or unexpected output? (Please include actual output and expected output)

Comment: You have a race condition here: `next[j] = next[next[j]];`. Indeed, this depends on the order upon which you travel your `j` loop, so trying to parallelise it will just change the order and thereafter possibly change the result.

Comment: @Gilles Thanks for the reply. I eliminated the race condition by putting the if loop in a critical region. But this means that I am effectively now running the algorithm in a sequential fashion. Is there any other way I can eliminate the race (I don't want to change the algorithm).

Comment: This is more than just a race condition actually. The trouble is that this algorithm is fundamentally not parallelisable, because the order of execution or the `j` loop matters here. So you could get away with using the `ordered` directive, but ultimately you would end-up with a sequential algorithm. Therefore, if you want to get it truly parallel, you have to fundamentally change your algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be possible with a second set of arrays.
Correct me if I am wrong.

When you take two arrays and two pointers `next_new` and `next_old` and two arrays and two pointers `Rp_new` and `Rp_old`, it should do the trick.

You write to the **new** arrays, while reading from the **old** and swapping pointers after each Round.

```
Rp_new[j] = Rp_old[j] + Rp_old[next_old[j]];

next_new[j] = next_old[next_old[j]];
```